# AssertNotEqual returns wrong result

Tags: python, arrays, unit-testing, exception, assertion

i have the following function:

`assertNotEqual(np.array(p.ideal_boundaries_lower()).all(),np.array(p.ideal_boundaries_upper()).all())`

the two tested functions return a table with the same dimensions, however the values are slightly different (but not as slightly that it may not get catched anymore, we're talking about differences of 0.01 to 10). I know that the values are not the same, I checked that manually. However, I get an AssertionError, stating that both are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing the results of [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) on each one of your arrays. The two arrays could be different, but the results of this could still be the same.

Perhaps you should change your code to

```
assertFalse((np.array(p.ideal_boundaries_lower()) == np.array(p.ideal_boundaries_upper())).all())
```

which would check that it's not true that all entries are equal.

Comment: This returns me `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` again, which brought me to using .all() in the first place..

Comment: @Paul1911 There was a parentheses issue. Try now?